# Can I set Leaflet background as transparent?

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

I would like to not have a background in Leaflet.js, so my marker layers floats on top of whatever is layered behind the map. In my case, I want to layer leaflet instance with markers on top of a [world sun clock element.](https://github.com/GChristensen/sunligth-world-map-gadget)

Comment: Include crucial parts of your code in your question. Don't force people to search other sites to fix your mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically,you use a massive [DivIcon](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#divicon) as the icon for a `L.Marker`, place the sun clock widget in that `DivIcon`, disable clicks on said marker with `{clickable:false}`, and continue to update its position as needed. Sounds very hacky, but possibly workable.